# How to copy a text file through command prompt from a source machine to a destination machine when they are on the same network?

Tags: copy, robocopy

How should I copy a text file say CopyMe.txt from a machine A to a machine B? These two machines are on the same network. Each of these 2 machines need a username and password to log into remotely. I want to achieve this copy action through command prompt.

I have tried using ROBOCOPY command and here is what I have tried step by step:

1. Get the IP address of machine B say a.b.c.d
2. Log into machine A and open command prompt
3. Say the CopyMe.txt file is present on machine A's desktop. So I type the following: ROBOCOPY C:\Users\user_name\desktop\CopyMe.txt \a.b.c.d\C$\Users\user_name\desktop
4. I get the following error saying Error 5 (0x00000005) Getting File System Type of Destination \a.b.c.d\C$\Users\user_name\desktop\ Access is denied

Comment: Maybe try sharing the folder you're trying to access?

Comment: I tried your solution. Now I am NOT getting any access denied error but I am running into a different issue. It says invalid parameters. All I am doing is `ROBOCOPY \\network\shared\folder\path C:\Users\user_name\somepath sample.txt`